# Java String: difference between null and empty

Tags: java, string, null, comparison

I don'd understand the difference between a null String and an empty String in Java.

Suppose `String a = null`, and I want to see if a is null by using `a.isEmpty()` or `a.equals("null")`. Neither of these works. I have to use `a == null` to tell that if a is `null` or not.

From my understanding, if you use `==` between two strings, you are actually comparing their addresses or references in memory? Is this understanding right? I hope someone can clarify my confusion. Thanks in advance.

Comment: value == null tests the object reference to see if its null or not. If it's null, you cannot access the object properties like equals or isEmpty, as the reference points to nothing. The best option is to check for null first to avoid the possibility of a NullPointerException

Comment: See the duplicate, but isEmpty is the same as a string of length 0, null means there is no string at all

Comment: off topic, but why do people answer to this question, since it has been asked, properly answered, and correctly identified as duplicate ?

Comment: @njzk2 http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/4283/133242

Answer (score 4):

null ==> has no reference (no String is referenced)

"" ==> has a reference that points to string (which happen to be empty)

Answer (score 1):

You **always** use `==` when checking for any `null` reference. You can't use `Object#equals()` because, you can't call an instance method if you don't have an instance, and `null` specifically means "there is no instance!"

Comment: Noteworthy is that you CAN pass a null reference to equals() since by convention it should be able to handle null (evaluate it to false).

Answer (score 0):

You're correct: `==` tests whether two Strings are in fact references to the same `String` object.

An empty `String` object is exactly what it says on the tin, while `null` refers to the lack of an object reference whatsoever. With an empty String, you can call all the `String` methods and generally treat it like any other `String` - but with `null` there is no object to call the methods on so you get a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: NullPointerException was exactly what I got when running my code. This exception was not gone until I check by a == null. Thanks for all the replies! will check the duplicate thread.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
a.equals("null")
```

compares the strin with the string "null".

`null` is a reserved keyword in Java, that means that variable doesn't refer to anything.

```
a.isEmpty()
```

checks if the string has no characters. i.e. it is equal to `""`.

Answer (score 0):

An empty string is literally just "" whereas null is a reference to nothing. So anything that is null has not been instantiated but something that is empty exists but just doesn't contain any values.

The thing to remember in Java is that String is an object not a raw datatype like int or double. The "==" only compares equality between values not object references so for Strings and other objects you need to use .equals.

Answer (score 0):

`String` is a reference variable to a String object in the memory. If the `String` is null it means it is not referencing any String object.

In `a.equals("null");` you are comparing the value of the String object in the memory to the literal "null". To check whether a String variable is null (means not reference a String object in the memory) use `a == null`.